# Magento 2 Composer Install Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: magento2, composer

I am installing Magento 2.4.3 community edition in my local machine.

**Machine Specifications:**

```
1.Linux (Ubuntu OS)
2.Nginx 
3.Php 7.3 and Mysql
```

I've set the memory limit as -1 (unlimited) and all other basic settings.

I am using the following command to install the community edition in my local

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.3 magento243
```

But during the installation i am getting the following error message.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted
```

For your further reference herewith I've attached a screen.
[image]

Advance thanks for your better support.

Comment: Please follow the given link, may be it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212475/composer-require-runs-out-of-memory-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-161

Answer (score 2):

You can run composer specifying more memory for it:

```
$>which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer

$>php -d memory_limit=4G /usr/local/bin/composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.3 magento243
```